# Issue with Document Library (Preview) and Name field appearing in view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, spfield, modern-pages

When I add a document library (preview) to a modern site page in SharePoint Online, it adds the name field to the view even though it is not in the view in the default library:

**Original Library**
[image: Original Library]
**View Settings**
[image: View Settings, name is not checked]
**Name appearing**
[image: Name appearing in the view]

Any recommendations? Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue.

It seems that the "Type (icon)" and "Name" field are the fixed fields that will always display in "Document Library (preview)".

Currently, there is no method to remove these fields. It is by design.

As a workaround, we can use “Embed” modern web part instead. Put the address of your library into the Embed textbox, it will display the library view (not whole page) from this address.

```
https://technet.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>/SitePages/Forms/pages.aspx
```

[image]

Comment: That workaround works, thank you for taking the time to reproduce. It's not the most aesthetically pleasing option so I may need to find a better way to recreate these pages. I'll be needed to display multiple views on a page to create a procedure manual.

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: this really needs to be addressed - it is pointless to have the option to hide the column if all it does is display an empty column that takes up all the space - also the column cannot be re-ordered, which is also useless.